# How to use css transform to build a 45-degree inverted trapezoid?

Tags: css

How to use css to build a 45-degree inverted trapezoid?

```
.inverted-trapezoid {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1.5em 0em 1.5em 0em;
    color: white;
    height: 1em;
    z-index: 0;
    // margin: 3em;
}
.inverted-trapezoid::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: red;
    border-bottom: none;
    transform: perspective(9.5em) rotateX(-45deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

We can use the transform to make a  inverted trapezoid,but how can we make  45-degree exactly?

Answer (score 1):

use `clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%);` for inverted trapezoid

```
<div class="Inverted-trapezoid"></div>

.Inverted-trapezoid{width:200px; height:200px;background:#000;margin-bottom:50px; margin-right:20px; clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%);}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it with borders:

```css
.trapezoid {
  border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent ;
  border-width: 0 100px 100px 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.inverted-trapezoid {
  border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: 100px 100px 0 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="trapezoid"></div>
  <div class="inverted-trapezoid"></div>
</div>
```